# Is it feasible to creating a mobile application that communicates client to client?

Tags: android, iphone, sockets, mobile, ios5

I am thinking about writing a mobile application that uses a central coordinator to organise communication but after that point each node should communicate directly with one another.

Each device has a HTTP server, which receives requests from other devices.

Concerns:

- Devices behind proxys and routers.
- Networks preventing inbound communication.
- Battery consumption maintaining a listening http server while the app is running.
- Gaining access to the public facing IP of the phone.
- Possibly using a randomised or alternative port scheme, if its difficult to select a port to use.
- Going further than HTTP and having a TLS server on each device

Questions:

- How feasible is this approach?
- are there any other major apps that use this approach?
- Is HTTP the best mechanism or would a socket be preferable?

[image: example of the scheme]
<sub>(source: [johnflan.com](http://johnflan.com/scratch/ishot-99.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Your concerns are all valid and relevant.  For example, many mobile networks have their users behind NAT.  Very hard to get inbound initiated access.

I think that is why XMPP services are so pervasive.  Which is something you might want to investigate as a mechanism for small message passing.

There are other message passing and RPC types protocols out there, but without further info on your application, it's requirements, and it's constraints, it is hard to tell what would be most applicable.

Comment: Its a chat application, it was hoping to keep it decentralised as much as possible to allay the current security fears. However my concern is using something like XMPP will not give me the control I require to organise chatters into the appropriate groups.

Comment: XMPP is quite a powerful medium.  It does require a server, and could be the server you show in your diagram.  IRC is another example of a chat application, and is server based.  If all your target devices are reachable without NAT, and their firewalls allow inbound connections, which is typically representative of devices within an organization, then you won't have issues.  On the other hand, if you are working with internet based devices, you will have an up-hill struggle of peer-peer.  You could look into how bit-torrent works and emulate that solution.  Which works for some but not others.